# Failing to get value from WebKitCSSMatrix

Tags: javascript, css, webkit-transform

I need to get the x and y values of translate3d proprety of a div, for witch i use the code below:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle($(videoContainer).get(0));
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);

var verticalOffset = parseInt(matrix.m41);
var horizontalOffset = parseInt(matrix.m42);
```

When i'm using a breackpoint in Chrome's inspector to see if the values are correct, it's working fine. If i enter an alert() in the code it's working fine, but if none of these two 'stops' are in the code, the values of verticalOffset and horizontalOffset are 0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The elements i was trying was animated using jquery.animate and as i tryed to get the values at document.ready the values were 0

I delayed my code for 1sec and now i have acces to the values